# Removing list within lists based on nth element

Tags: prolog

I've got a list of lists, for example:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4, 3], [1, 4, 5, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6, 5], 
[2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 6, 7, 6], [2, 5, 7, 10], [3, 4, 7, 12], [2, 6, 8, 12]]
```

I'd like to get the last element of  and check to see if is the same as the 4th element of any of the other lists. If it is the same then leave the list alone, but if it is unique then remove the list. So in the example above I would be left with:

```
[[3, 4, 7, 12], [2, 6, 8, 12]]
```

Essentially I want to be remove all the lists where the last element is unique.
I've written a predicate to get the nth element:

```
my_membership(X, [X|_]).                           
my_membership(X, [_|Tail]) :-  
  my_membership(X, Tail).
```

where:

```
my_membership([_,_,_,Fourth],[[3, 4, 7, 12], [2, 6, 8, 12]]).
```

gives:

```
Fourth = 12 
Fourth = 12
```

Comment: Did you intend also to keep, `[2, 3, 5, 6]` and `[1, 6, 7, 6]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by building two basic predicates:

```
last([X], X).
last([_|T], X) :- last(T, X).

forth([_,_,_,F|_], F).
```

The first predicate extracts the last element of a list; the second predicate extracts the forth element of a list.

Now you can make a predicate that counts how many tomes an element `X` appears in forth place in any of the lists of a list of lists. Below, `H` in `[H|T]` is a list:

```
matching_forth([], _, 0).
matching_forth([H|T], X, R) :- forth(H, X), matching_forth(T, X, RR), R is RR + 1.
matching_forth([_|T], X, R) :- matching_forth(T, X, R).
```

With these predicates in place you can build a predicate for checking your condition. It will have three clauses - for a situation when the list is empty, for when the head list has a matching forth element in another list, and for situations when it doesn't:

```
my_membership([], [], _).
my_membership([H|T], [H|R], A) :-
   last(H, X), matching_forth(A, X, C), C > 1, my_membership(T, R, A).
my_membership([_|T], R, A) :- my_membership(T, R, A).
```

The first and last clauses are self-explanatory. The middle clause extracts the last element from the head list, counts how many times it matches the forth element in the original list of lists (`A` stands for "all"), and adds `H` to the result when there is a match. Adding happens through unification with the head of the result list.

Finally, you need a `my_membership/2` predicate to start off the recursive chain that passes along the original list of lists:

```
my_membership(L, R) :-  my_membership(L, R, L).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/eFCHCQ)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for and very well explained. Thank you!

Comment: Just using it now, but it's giving me multiple answers when pressing `;`. Is there anyway for it to only generate 1 answer? I've had a go using the `!` but haven't figured it out.

Comment: @JaAnTr Did you try `my_membership(L, R) :-  my_membership(L, R, L), !.` ? I am not sure if this is going to work, but it's worth giving a try. I don't have access to an interpreter at the moment, and I am not sure how to simulate pressing `;` with the online SWI. Another approach would be to insert the cut `!` after `C > 1` condition.

Comment: @JaAnTr I tried both placements of `!` with `findall`, either one produces a single solution ([demo with "cut"](http://ideone.com/TKvoPQ)).

Comment: I have tried both placements of `!` but I think it might be leading of an infinite loop once the `;` is pressed. This is part of a piece of work which can be evaluated with a marking script. Without any cuts I get told that there are 6 answers when there should be 1. When I add in the cuts the marking script never finishes, which I assume is the result of it getting stuck in some sort of loop. Likewise pressing `;` in SWI-Prolog causes it to stop responding.

Comment: @JaAnTr That is really odd: the cut has solved it for `findall` (see demo) so there should be no issues with the script either. Does the marking script simply call `my_membership(SomeInput, Result)`, or is there anything else going on? You can try fronting the call from the marking script with `findall` and extracting the first result (see link in the comment above for calling `findall`).

Comment: I'm having no luck with getting findall to work. Here is the relevant part of the code if you're interested. Ideone, isn't displaying the full output as it is 1747 lists within a list. https://ideone.com/Io1KR0

Comment: @JaAnTr I do not fully understand how your program is tested, but I think that you need a cut in your `s1` predicate as well -- between generating numbers and finding solutions ([like this](https://ideone.com/y9UsOz)). The program runs forever without this cut.

Comment: That's solved it, the marking script now finds no multiple answers. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying to build a similar set of predicates that do a similar job and I don't understand one thing. What is the difference between `last` and `forth` as a list only ever contains 4 elements so surely `forth` is the same as `last`? Or is `last` used for getting the last 4 element list?

Comment: @JaAnTr The question does not say that all lists will have exactly four elements (although all the examples do have exactly four elements). If you are guaranteed that all lists have exactly four elements, you can drop `last`.

Comment: Really sorry I've got one more quick question. How would I modify your code so that it does the opposite, essentially keeping the list if the 4th element is unique? I tried changing `C > 1` to `C < 1`, tried changing around the predicate header(?) and tried creating a new list and adding to it if `new_membership([H|T], [H|R], A, Reject) :-  failed. All 3 didn't work and I've made no progress for a few hours. Thank you.

Comment: @JaAnTr `C < 1` wouldn't work, it should be either `C =:= 1` or `C < 2`.

Comment: I've tried both suggestions but `my_membership2([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6]], X).` is still just returning `X = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5, 6]].` instead of `[[1,2,5,6]]`.

Comment: @JaAnTr I see what's going on. Add a cut after `forth(H,H)` in the second clause of `matching_forth` ([Demo](http://ideone.com/cXiviH)).

Comment: Truly one last question, sorry! I've now tried to modify it to do the same thing but instead of the fourth element, use the third. I have changed the predicates that make it get the fourth but I am just getting an empty list. If you could take a quick look that'd be fantastic. https://ideone.com/M3qEO4

Comment: @JaAnTr That's because in your example there are no sub-lists where the last element would match the third element of some other list. It works fine with a different input ([link](https://ideone.com/OFH2y8)). If you want to match third-to-third (as opposed to third-to-last matches that you are currently doing) replace uses of `last/2` with `third/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different twist on a potential solution. It uses an accumulator to collect members that we've seen already and checks along the way. The result saves those that have either been seen or are currently in the tail. It requires the use of the built-in, `memberchk/2`.

```
my_membership(L, R) :-
    my_membership(L, [], R).

my_membership([], _, []).
my_membership([X|T], Acc, R) :-
    X = [_,_,_,D],
    (   memberchk([_,_,_,D], Acc)
    ->  R = [X|T1],
        Acc1 = Acc
    ;   memberchk([_,_,_,D], T)
    ->  R = [X|T1],
        Acc1 = [X|Acc]
    ;   R = T1,
        Acc1 = Acc
    ),
    my_membership(T, Acc1, T1).

| ?- my_membership([[1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4, 3], [1, 4, 5, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6, 5],
[2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 6, 7, 6], [2, 5, 7, 10], [3, 4, 7, 12], [2, 6, 8, 12]], L).

L = [[2,3,5,6],[1,6,7,6],[3,4,7,12],[2,6,8,12]]

yes
```